# Go Authorization Header not being sent

Tags: go, http-headers

### Solution:

The issue was that our request went to Http... instead of http**s**. This means that the Go library removes the auth header as it treats it as a redirect.

### There is an Update to this question at the bottom

So I am kinda new to Go and am currently trying to fix a bug in a small service of ours.
Its basic funtion is to take in a request that needs (MSAL) authorization, getting that authorization and then forwarding the request to the specific endpoint.

It does it like this:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", ProxyRequest)

func ProxyRequest(wr http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    auth, err := tokenHelper.GetAuthorization()
    client := &http.Client{}

    req.URL = newUrl
    req.Host = newUrl.Host
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", *auth)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
}
```

This works fine, as in the header if printed looks like this: `Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ...` and the rest of the headers and body are still present.

If I copy the request into Postman everything works fine and the debugging Output on my server looks like this:

[image: Cropped due to privacy but I think you get the point]

but if I sent the Request using Go the Servers Debugger Output looks like this:

[image: Once again cropped due to privacy concerns]

The only difference being that with Postman it includes the authorization header while with Go it is not being sent. This of course results in the request being rejected.

I have searched the Internet and this site quite a bit but as of yet I can not seem to find the mistake in our code. Any help would be appreciated

### Edit:

So I tried both things mentioned in the answers, but I am just going to post the complete new Request one as that is what @izca recommended:

```
    newReq, err := http.NewRequest(req.Method, newUrl.String(), req.Body)

    newReq.Header.Add("Authorization", *auth)

    log.Println(newReq.Header)
    resp, err := client.Do(newReq)
```

Which results in exactly the same behaviour. The Request is going to the correct endpoint and is completely barebone, without Authorization Header.

[image]

Log Output:

```
map[Authorization:[Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL....]]
```

Comment: You are setting the headers for the response and not for the request you want to make.

Comment: Trying your edited code, I get the `Authorization` header at the server. You might have an intermediate proxy that removes that header.

Answer (score 1):

`req` is the HTTP request of the incoming connection. You can't (shouldn't) reuse that to outgoing HTTP requests.

Attempting to do so, `client.Do()` will return an error:

> http: Request.RequestURI can't be set in client requests

Do create a new [`http.Request`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) using [`http.NewRequest()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequest) or [`http.NewRequestWithContext()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequestWithContext), and use that for an outgoing request, pass that to `client.Do()`.

Comment: See my edit. This still results in the Auth Header not being sent

Answer (score 1):

In extension to what @icza has suggested, if you really want to forward the same request like in the case of reverse proxy scenario, you can use `req.Clone(newCtx)` which will deep copy the original request and returns a new Request.